# Разложение проекта по директориям

Tags: c++

Как правильней разложить проектные файлы по директориям?

Некоторые ide генерируют папки source, headers, objects c абсолютно идентичной иерархией директорий, но находятся там файлы с разным расширением. Встречал когда одна иерархия директорий проекта, но h и cpp файлы вместе сложенны.

Какой способ правильней и чем?

Comment: Естественно лучше, когда проект разбит на подкаталоги, где в каждом каталоге хранятся файлы одного типа. Так легче искать файлы, переносить их в другие каталоги и совместно использовать с другими проектами.  Для простых учебных проектов лучше, когда все хранится в одном каталоге.:)

Comment: Я обычно разделяю по каталогам, но группирую логически: модели, утилиты, бизнес-логика, интерфейс и т. п.

Comment: А так, правильного способа нет, делайте как _вам_ удобно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для мелких проектов группировка по типам может быть удобна.

Но чем больше проект, тем менее удобной будет группировка по типу файлов. Всё время придётся держать несколько папок развёрнутыми. Например, ты меняешь что-то в cpp-файле, что требует внести изменения и в h-файл. И вот у тебя уже одновременно в solution explorer'е до одной и той же сущности развёрнуто два весьма жирных каталога. Поэтому лучше сгруппировать логически на основе сущностей, сложив всё, относящееся к одной сущности, в одну папку.